# Grails Unit Testing Pass By Reference Doesn't Work When Mocking

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, spock

I have a unit test where I'm mocking a service class to save a Domain. Originally, my controller method looked like this:

```
def save(Long organizationId, Convention convention) {
  conventionService.save(organizationId, convention)

  if (convention.hasErrors()) {
    response.status = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY.value()
    respond convention.errors
  } else {
    response.status = HttpStatus.CREATED.value()
    respond convention
  }
}
```

Generally, this works because Java is pass by reference so the `convention` passed into the save method is the same `convention` object throughout the method. However, when mocking the `conventionService.save` method, pass by reference doesn't work. Adjusting my method to account for this:

```
def save(Long organizationId, Convention convention) {
  convention = conventionService.save(organizationId, convention)

  if (convention.hasErrors()) {
    response.status = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY.value()
    respond convention.errors
  } else {
    response.status = HttpStatus.CREATED.value()
    respond convention
  }
}
```

allows my test to pass because the `convention` object is what I'm expecting from my mock:

```
1 * service.save(1, _) >> new Convention(
       id: 1,
       name: 'Con 1',
       description: 'This is a pretty cool convention, everyone should go',
       startDate: new Date(),
       endDate: new Date()+10,
       organization: organization)
```

My question is, is this expected behavior or a bug that I should be reporting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is this expected behavior or a bug that I should be
>   reporting?

This is expected behavior.  This is not a bug you should be reporting.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I assumed as much but wanted to be sure. I'm going to have to explain this in a couple of weeks.

Comment: "I'm going to have to explain this in a couple of weeks." - Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I believe so. I understand the basic logic of it with regards to mocking in general. I just wanted to be sure there wasn't any Spock or Groovy/Grails magic that would have been manipulating my expectation.